# Seeking details on the PanchYudha Stotra

Tags: scripture, vishnu, reference-request, stotra, author

I recently came across this stotra and have since been searching for its origin and author. I would really appreciate it if someone could let me its composer, which scripture it is written in, and how it came into being.